# Iterate through each digit in a number

Tags: java, math, numbers, iteration

I am trying to create a program that will tell if a number given to it is a "[Happy Number](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Happy_number)" or not. Finding a happy number requires each digit in the number to be squared, and the result of each digit's square to be added together.

In Python, you could use something like this:

```
SQUARE[d] for d in str(n)
```

But I can't find how to iterate through each digit in a number in Java. As you can tell, I am new to it, and can't find an answer in the Java docs.

Comment: If you're done with the question, please accept the answer.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

You can use a modulo 10 operation to get the rightmost number and then divide the number by 10 to get the next number.

```
long addSquaresOfDigits(int number) {
    long result = 0;
    int tmp = 0;
    while(number > 0) {
        tmp = number % 10;
        result += tmp * tmp;
        number /= 10;
    }
    return result;
}
```

You could also put it in a string and turn that into a char array and iterate through it doing something like `Math.pow(charArray[i] - '0', 2.0);`

Comment: @Isaac Lewis: Added a some (untested) code which I think can do the trick of getting you the result of the adding the squares of each digit.

Comment: You need to fix the 'number / 10' to assign somewhere.

Comment: Ah, please don't use Math.pow to square a number.  `result += ((number%10) * (number % 10))` would be better (or use an extra variable to spare the double `%`). And your `number / 10` should be `number /= 10`, I think.

Comment: Good observations Darron and Paulo.

Answer (score 8):

Assuming the number is an integer to begin with:

```
int num = 56;
String strNum = "" + num;
int strLength = strNum.length();
int sum = 0;

for (int i = 0; i < strLength; ++i) {
  int digit = Integer.parseInt(strNum.charAt(i));
  sum += (digit * digit);
}
```

Answer (score 8):

I wondered which method would be quickest to split up a positive number into its digits in Java, String vs modulo

```
  public static ArrayList<Integer> splitViaString(long number) {

    ArrayList<Integer> result = new ArrayList<>();
    String s = Long.toString(number);

    for (int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++) {
      result.add(s.charAt(i) - '0');
    }
    return result; // MSD at start of list
  }
```

vs

```
  public static ArrayList<Integer> splitViaModulo(long number) {

    ArrayList<Integer> result = new ArrayList<>();

    while (number > 0) {
      int digit = (int) (number % 10);
      result.add(digit);
      number /= 10;
    }
    return result; // LSD at start of list
  }
```

Testing each method by passing `Long.MAX_VALUE` 10,000,000 times, the string version took 2.090 seconds and the modulo version 2.334 seconds. (Oracle Java 8 on 64bit Ubuntu running in Eclipse Neon)

So not a lot in it really, but I was a bit surprised that String was faster

Answer (score 1):

In the above example we can use:

```
int digit = Character.getNumericValue(strNum.charAt(i));
```

instead of

```
int digit = Integer.parseInt(strNum.charAt(i));
```

Comment: From Review: What example? Could you please edit your question and be more precise? The order of answers may change in SO depending on their votes.

Answer (score 1):

You can turn the integer into a string and iterate through each char in the string. As you do that turn that char into an integer

Answer (score 0):

This code returns the first number (after 1) that fits your description.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int i=2;
    // starting the search at 2, since 1 is also a happy number
    while(true) {
        int sum=0;
        for(char ch:(i+"").toCharArray()) { // casting to string and looping through the characters.
            int j=Character.getNumericValue(ch);
            // getting the numeric value of the current char.
            sum+=Math.pow(j, j);
            // adding the current digit raised to the power of itself to the sum.
        }
        if(sum==i) {
            // if the sum is equal to the initial number
            // we have found a number that fits and exit.
            System.out.println("found: "+i);
            break;
        }
        // otherwise we keep on searching
        i++;
    }
}
```

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply. [From Review](/review/late-answers/26237566)

Comment: sorry, but this is my first answer