# Happy numbers checker not working correctly

Tags: java, if-statement

```
int Cnt(){
    return Count (10);
}

int Count (int init){
    int u = init % 10;
    int t = (init % 100) - u;
    int u2 = u * u;
    int t2 = t * t;
    int m = u2 + t2;
    if(m <= 1)
        System.out.println("Happy!");
    else {
        return Count (m);
    }
```

This code should (in theory) check if number is [Happy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Happy_number), and if it's not sets initial value to be same as the result and whole process repeats.
Infinite loop should occur if number is not happy.
However none of this happens, does anyone know how to make this work?

Comment: Does the code compile for you? You have to place return statement inside of `if` or after `if-else` clause

Comment: What happens if you have to check a number like 78?  The next number in sequence is 49 + 64 = 113.  When you check 113, what does you code do?  What are the values of `t` and `u` in that case?  (Better to use `tens` and `units` as variable names; get into good habits early.)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Iterate through each digit in a number](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5009591/iterate-through-each-digit-in-a-number)

Comment: What use is an infinite loop if the number isn't Happy? When you say _none of this happens_ - would you edit your question to say what exactly does happen?

Answer (score 0):

Since this is homework I am not putting in the answer... but here is the clue..

**You are not handling 3 digit numbers well.**

`t=init%100-u` computes to `10%100-0 = 10`

and once `m=u2+t2` i.e. `m=0+100` reaches to `100` and your program doesn't handle 3 digit numbers. Hope this helps.

add following...

```
int h = init/100;
int h2 = h * h;
int m = u2+t2+h2;
```

and it should keep you going... :)

Answer (score 0):

According to the Wiki article that you linked, you have to repeat the process of summing the digits of the digits in each number. For the example of 7:

```
7^2 = 49
49  = 4^2 + 9^2 = 16 + 81 = 97
97  = 9^2 + 7^2 = 81 + 49 = 130
130 = 1^2 + 3^2 = 10
10  = 1^2 = 1
```

I see a few problems with your code. First, you haven't divided your tens digit by 10, which means for the number 52, you will get u = 2, and t = 50, rather than 5. This part, I'm sure you can easily fix.

Second, it looks like you will never reach a conclusion if your number is unhappy. For example with the number 4, you will reach 16, 37, 72, 53, 34, 25, 29, 85, 89, 145, 42, 20, 4. But your program, since you have no way of checking that you've entered a loop, will run until you run out of memory.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the approach as outlined in the [article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Happy_number) you referenced:

```
private static boolean isHappy(int number)
{
   List<Integer> set = new ArrayList<Integer>();

   while (number > 1 && !set.contains(number))
   {
       set.add(number);

       number = sumSquaresOfDigits(number);
   }

   return number == 1;
}

private static int sumSquaresOfDigits(int number)
{
    String numberString = Integer.toString(number);

    int result = 0;

    for (char character : numberString.toCharArray())
    {
        int digit = Character.digit(character, 10);

        result += digit * digit;
    }

    return result;
}
```

This can be done more efficiently by computing the squares of all 10 digits (0-9) and storing the results in an integer array.

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.io.*;
class happy_no
{
    void happy(double n)
    {
        int c=0;
        double s=0;
        double d,p,i,_sa;
        for(i=1;i<=n;i++)
        {
            while(n!=0)
            {
                d=n%10;
                p=d*d;
                s=s+p;
                n=n/10;
            }
            if(s==1)
            {
                System.out.println("HAPPY NO.");
                break;
            }
            else
            {
                n=s;
            }
        }
    }
    public static void main()throws IOException
    {
        InputStreamReader read=new InputStreamReader(System.in);
        BufferedReader in=new BufferedReader(read);
        double a;
        System.out.println("ENTER A NO.");
        a=Double.parseDouble(in.readLine());
        happy_no obj=new happy_no();
        obj.happy(a);
    }
```