# Modulo-use function of sum of positive integers digits?

Tags: function, python-3.x, module

I created a function that sums the digits of a given positive integer:

```
def digit_sum(n):
    tot = 0
    for i in str(n):
        tot += int(i)
    return tot
```

but I know that using mod10, mod 100 etc you can find the digits of a given number. So I thought there is an alternative way to construct the function without having the back and forth integer convert. Any ideas?

Comment: Possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5009591/iterate-through-each-digit-in-a-number

Comment: @maxwellb i got the logic of it. in python i think it is sthing like this   
    def digit_sum(n):
        tot = 0
        while n > 9:
            tot += n%10
            n = n // 10
        tot = tot + n
        return tot

Answer (score 1):

Shown here in Javascript: http://jsfiddle.net/bhQLa/

Break the digits out individually using

```
// Loop through the digits without using string
var base = 1;
while (base * 10 <= num) base *= 10;
while (base >= 1) {
    var digit = (num - (num % base)) / base;
    digits.push(digit);
    num -= digit * base;
    base /= 10;
}
// ---
```

Then sum them up. First increment the base to a maximum. Then decrement the base after grabbing the digit by `(num - (num % base)) / base`. Don't forget to decrement your working number, then the base.