# The sum of all odd digits of an input

Tags: java, loops

How to compute the sum of all 'odd digits of an input' using 'loop'. (For example, if the input is 32677, the sum would be 3 + 7 + 7 = 17.)

I can't quite figure out how to do that, can someone please help me out. This is what I have done so far, I don't know how to complete it or whether I have its right or wrong.

Any help would be appreciated!

```
System.out.println("Enter a number: ");
String input = in.nextLine();
int length = input.length();

int sum = 0;
int digits = 0;

for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
    if (length % 2 == 1) {
        digits += i;
        sum = digits++;
    }
}
System.out.println(sum);
```

Comment: why did you add this check: if(length%2==1){ ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Iterate through each digit in a number](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5009591/iterate-through-each-digit-in-a-number)

Comment: You aren't too far, you found the main logic. Few steps are missing: inside your loop, you need to get the character indexed at `i` (e.g. with `String#charAt`), then you need to convert it into a number (e.g. with `Integer#valueOf`). Only then, you can do your modulo on it to know whether odd or even, and add it to the sum if odd.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your interpretation of the digits inside of input is not working this way.

```
System.out.println("Enter a number: ");
String input = in.nextLine();
int length = input.length();

int sum = 0;

for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
    int digit = input.charAt(i) - '0';
    if (digit % 2 == 1) {
        System.out.println("Add digit: " + digit);
        sum += digit;
    }
}
System.out.println(sum);
```

Comment: Hi Milgo, what does +1 do exactly in this specific code: Integer digit = Integer.valueOf(input.substring(i, i + 1));
Am just intrested and want to learn

Comment: You get a part of input, a sub string, between two indices. You start with the character at index i and end at index i + 1, so in the end you only get one character.
I would prefer charAt(i), but that returns a 'char' which is misinterpreted as Integer.

Comment: @Milgo, you could be using `charAt` too, and it would be even simpler to get the digit value: `int digit = input.charAt(i) - '0';` :)

Comment: @AlexRudenko The output shows a totally wrong output, am I doing something wrong with your way?

Comment: @chabztar01, please clarify.  Both initial version and the updated one work fine for integer numbers without decimal or thousand separators.  Did you try to input a non-integer number containing other characters than digits?

Comment: @AlexRudenko I changed it to the following:

System.out.println("Enter a number: ");
        String input = in.nextLine();
        int length = input.length();

        int sum = 0;

        for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
            int digit = input.charAt(i);
            if (digit % 2 == 1) {
                System.out.println(digit);
                sum += digit;
            }
        }
        System.out.println(sum);

And the output showed the following:

Enter a number: 
32677,
51,
55,
55,
161

Comment: @AlexRudenko sorry, it looks so messy when I put the code in the comment

Comment: @chabztar01, you need to subtract the value of `'0'` as it is written above to convert a char `'0', '1',..'9'` to integer number `0, 1, 2,.. 9`

Answer (score 3):

Here comes a Java8-based solution:

```
final int result = input.chars()//make a stream of chars from string
                        .mapToObj(String::valueOf) // make every character a String to be able to use parseInt later
                        .mapToInt(Integer::parseInt) // transform character in int
                        .filter(i -> i % 2 == 1) // filter out even numbers
                        .sum();
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to use String if your input is not so long.
also for safe side use long datatype.
Here is the working code with comments (explain each step).

```
long sumOddDigits(long value){
    long temp = value; // copy in temp variable
    long sum = 0;
    while(temp > 0){
      int digit = temp%10; // get last digit of number. example: 227 gives 7.
      temp = temp / 10; // remove that last digit from number.227 will be 22.
      if(digit % 2 == 1){
        sum += digit;
      }
    }
    return sum;
}
```

Comment: I think this is a really nice solution since you don't need any data conversion. If you use this solution you may also use `Scanner.nextInt()` and `Scanner.hasNextInt()` to make sure that the user can only input `Integer` values and catch inputs that are not `Integer` values.

Answer (score 0):

In your loop, use `Integer.parseInt(input.charAt(i))` to get the number at position i.

`if(length%2==1){` that doesn't make sense here. You want to check if your number is odd, not the length of your string.